# What does "$Y\mid X=x$" mean?

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

In statistics, what does "$Y\mid X=x$" mean? ($Y$ and $X$ are discrete random variables)

"$\mid$" is not "$\div$", right?

Please help me.
It will be a great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself $Y|X=x$ has no meaning. But quantities like $E(Y|X=x), P(Y \leq y|X=x)$ have a meaning. Here $|X=x$ means ''
given $X=x$' so  these quantities are conditional expectations and conditional probabilities.